# difference in svg rendering between browser and Illustrator

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I have an svg, which I created from a Sketchup model (using Layout to make it into a pdf, then using Illustrator to turn the line drawing into an svg). It’s supposed to look like [this](http://cool-house.nl/#Woningen).

That svg is quite large, though, because it has a lot of duplicate paths. So in Illustrator I outlined the paths and combined them all into one shape. This makes the svg almost four times smaller. However, in the browser, it now looks like [this](http://robinberghuijs.com/overview.svg). Some lines (which aren't really lines anymore) look like they disappear. (It looks the same in Illustrator.)

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: I cannot see the actual problem, would be fine if you could show a bit more precisly which lines you are talkig about and which errors actually appear. I had a look on both images and they seem to work for me.

Comment: That's going to be like looking for a needle in a haystack. Make a drawing which only consists of the problem areas and cut that down till you've got a simple testcase.

Answer (score 0):

What it suppose look like, there in that we have 5 floors and 2 of the side boxes  are frozen, and in the resulted one none of them are frozen and there is a split on hover, I mean the entire floor is not getting highlighted.

I think you should look in to the grouping of these layers. As you said it, you exported the Sketchup file into PDF. Usually PDF files regroup objects while exporting. I suggest you to look in to exporting options and if that is not possible then I think you need to check the layers structure and the grouping stays as is, in both Sketchup and illustrator of that PDF.